# Pinescript Trading view current price only

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

So I use High Low bars but want current price to plot a small dash across showing the current price. I don't like the line all the way across as the default program provides. I have written something that does close to what I want but it marks the history of previous closes which I don't want. I would be willing to have the previous be transparent if that is the only way to have this work. Any suggestions.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Current Price Line", overlay=true)

// Get the current price
currentPrice = close

// Check if the current bar is the last bar in the chart
isLastBar = barstate.islast

// Draw the current price as a short red line only on the current bar
line.new(x1 = isLastBar ? bar_index : na, y1 = isLastBar ? currentPrice : na, x2 = isLastBar ? bar_index + 1 : na, y2 = isLastBar ? currentPrice : na, color = color.red, width = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you only want to see the high and low of previous bars and only see the close on the current bar. You can create a line using the var variable and then delete the previous line once a new bar is created. I simplified your code as well.

```
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

var line closePrice = na
if barstate.islast
    (closePrice[1]).delete()
    closePrice := line.new(x1 = bar_index, y1 = close, x2 = bar_index + 1, y2 = close, color = color.red, width = 2)
```